# Not giving nearest distance from distance matrix in google OR solver

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

**I am using google or tools to get the root from distance matrix but my constrains is to start from

nearest distance but solver is giving unexpected route. Below my distance matrix. My expected output is 1 to 10 could in sequence based on distance.**

```py
        data['distance_matrix']=[[1000.    451.13  508.64  543.41  577.64  611.88  646.12  672.58  689.2
              1231.78 1246.69]  
             [ 451.13 1000.    484.56  519.33  553.56  587.8   622.04  648.5   665.12
              1207.7  1222.61]  
             [ 508.64  460.8  1000.    485.58  519.81  554.05  588.29  614.75  631.37
              1173.95 1188.86]  
             [ 543.41  483.77  473.78 1000.    496.84  531.08  565.32  591.78  608.4
              1150.98 1165.89]  
             [ 577.64  506.5   496.51  485.34 1000.    508.35  542.59  569.05  585.67
              1128.25 1143.16]  
             [ 611.88  529.23  519.24  508.07  496.84 1000.    519.86  546.32  562.94
              1105.52 1120.43]  
             [ 646.12  551.96  541.97  530.8   519.57  508.35 1000.    523.59  540.21
              1082.79 1097.7 ]  
             [ 672.58  571.36  561.37  550.2   538.97  527.75  516.53 1000.    520.81
              1063.39 1078.3 ]  
             [ 689.2   587.98  577.99  566.82  555.59  544.37  533.15  520.81 1000.
              1046.77 1061.68]    
             [1231.78 1154.62 1144.63 1133.46 1122.23 1111.01 1099.79 1087.45 1070.83
              1000.    495.04]  
             [1246.69 1171.32 1161.33 1150.16 1138.93 1127.71 1116.49 1104.15 1087.53
               496.83   10.  ]]    
        manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
                        routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)  
            ...  
            transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)  
            
            routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)  
            search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()  
            search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (  
            routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)  
            solution= routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
```

**... Is there any way to add a constraint to solver to get route based on distance value order.if distance value 4, 3, 2 then my route point should be 4, 3, 2. ?**

Comment: Could you please put the matrix in a code block as well and restate your question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean for all i if j is nextVar(i) then `transit(i-1, i) >= transit(i, j)` ?

```py
solver = routing.solver()
for index in range(routing.size()):
  if routing.IsEnd(index):
    continue
  node = manager.IndexToNode(index)
  for next_index in range(routing.size()):
    if routing.IsEnd(next_index) or routing.IsStart(next_index):
      continue
    next_node = manager.IndexToNode(next_index)
    first_cond = routing.NextVar(index) == next_index
    for next_next_index in range(routing.size()):
      if routing.IsStart(next_next_index):
        continue
      next_next_node = manager.IndexToNode(next_next_index)
      second_cond = routing.NextVar(next_index) == next_next_index
      sovler.Add(first_cond * second_cond * distance_matrix[node][next_node] >= first_cond * second_cond * distance_matrix[next_node][next_next_node])
```

Comment: Lets take small matrix where we have valid value:
dist_matrix = [[1000.,   1000.,    571.36,  1000.], [1000.,   1000.,    546.32, 1000.], [571.36,   546.32, 1000.,   1078.3], [1000.,   1000.,   1078.3, 1000.]]
  0->2:571.36, 1->2:546.32, 2->0:571,2->1:546.32, 2->3:1078.3, 3->2:1078.3
 so here 2 is source point and three node is available to go 0,1,3. Now from 2 nearest distance is node 1 which have 546.32 meter distance.
 route should be like 1,0,3 or 1,3,0. I mean, first node should be nearest from source point.

Comment: this is the job of first heurisitc PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
ref: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_options#first_sol_options

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Mine thinking was same but not getting expected output. PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC is providing 3,2,1. so that's why, I am little worried about whether my understanding is wrong and there is another way to do that.

Comment: can any body explain, if I have solution strategy "PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC"  and providing dist_matrix = [[1000., 1000., 571.36, 1000.], [1000., 1000., 546.32, 1000.], [571.36, 546.32, 1000., 1078.3], [1000., 1000., 1078.3, 1000.]] to the solver then how it is deciding a route ? How it's working in back ground ? Just was checking [basic links](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/constraint_solver/routing/RoutingModel#ArcIsMoreConstrainedThanArc ) link but didn't get in detail.